# Solving the recurrence $a_n=aa_{n-1}+ba_{n-2}$ using formal power series.

Tags: combinatorics, complex-analysis, analysis, recurrence-relations

I am trying to solve this quesetion from Serge Lang's Complex analysis book.

> Exercise II.1.6 (Difference Equations). Given complex numbers $a_0,
>  a_1, a, b$ define $a_n$ for $n \geq 2$ by $$ a_n=a a_{n-1}+b
>  a_{n-2} $$ If we have a factorization $$ T^2-a T-b=(T-\alpha)\left(T-\alpha^{\prime}\right), \quad \text { and }
>  \alpha \neq \alpha^{\prime} $$ show that the numbers $a_n$ are given
> by $$ a_n=A \alpha^n+B \alpha^{\prime n} $$ with suitable $A, B$. Find
> $A, B$ in terms of $a_0, a_1, \alpha, \alpha^{\prime}$. HINT: Consider the
> power series $$ F(T)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n T^n $$ Show that it
> represents a rational function, and give its partial fraction
> decomposition.

We first use the standard method of generating functions to write

$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty a_n T^n = \sum_{n=2}^\infty aa_{n-1}T^n + \sum_{n=2}^\infty b a_{n-2}T^n.$$

Now, expanding terms, we have

$$a_2T^2+a_3T^3+a_4T^4+\dots = aa_1T^2+aa_2T^3+aa_3T^4 +\dots ba_0T^2+ba_1T^3+ba_2T^4+\dots.$$

Then, letting $F(T) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nT^n$, we can rewrite this as

$$F(T)(T^2-aT-b) = -aa_0T+a_1T^3+a_0T^2$$

which gives us the form of $F$ a a rational function, namely

$$F(T) = \frac{a_1T^3+a_0T^2-aa_0T}{(T^2-aT-b)} =\frac{a_1T^3+a_0T^2-aa_0T}{(T-\alpha)(T-\alpha')}.$$

Now, the question says to expand in partial fractions. The numerator is greater than the denominator, so we must perform polynomial long division. Doing this yields,

$$F(t) = (a_0+aa_1)+a_1T + \frac{(a_1b-a^2a)T + (a_0b+aa_1b)}{(T-\alpha)(T-\alpha')}.$$
Now, I am stuck. This is too messy to get anything useful from with partial fractions decomposition, and I can't figure out how to relate this back to obtain the form of the $a_n$. What can be done from here?

Comment: "we can rewrite this as" I think you should double-check this.

Answer (score 1):

Just for the heck of it,
I am posting here
my derivation of
the power series for
the general linear recurrence
and the expansion
in terms of the
roots of the characteristic polynomial
assuming that the
roots are all simple.

This is a
totally non-original working out
of the general homogeneous linear
recurrence.

If
$a_n
=\sum_{k=1}^m c_k a_{n-k}
$
for $n \ge m$,
find the generating function
$A(x)
=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n x^n
$
in terms of
$a_{0..m-1}$
and
$c_{1..m}$.

(This is undoubtedly a duplicate,
but I just wanted to work this out
from scratch.
The algebra and rearrangements of summations
is complicated enough
so that,
as usual,
I am hoping that
someone might have
a simpler derivation.)

Given the linear recurrence

$a_n
=\sum_{k=1}^m c_k a_{n-k}
$
for $n \ge m$.

Find the generating function
$A(x)
=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n x^n
$
in terms of
$a_{0..m-1}$
and
$c_{1..m}$.

My answer is

$A(x)
=\dfrac{\sum_{r=0}^{m-1}  x^r(a_r-\sum_{k=1}^{r} c_{k} a_{r-k})}{1-\sum_{k=1}^m c_k x^k}
$.

My derivation
(and this is a derivation, not a verification).

Let
$A_j(x)
=\sum_{n=0}^{j} a_n x^n
$
for
$j = 0$ to $m-1$.

$\begin{array}\\
A(x)
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n x^n\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{m-1} a_n x^n+\sum_{n=m}^{\infty} a_n x^n\\
&=A_{m-1}(x)+\sum_{n=m}^{\infty}  x^n\sum_{k=1}^m c_k a_{n-k}\\
&=A_{m-1}(x)+\sum_{k=1}^m c_k\sum_{n=m}^{\infty}  x^n  a_{n-k}\\
&=A_{m-1}(x)+\sum_{k=1}^m c_k x^k\sum_{n=m}^{\infty}  x^{n-k}  a_{n-k}\\
&=A_{m-1}(x)+\sum_{k=1}^m c_k x^k\sum_{n=m-k}^{\infty}  x^{n}  a_{n}\\
&=A_{m-1}(x)+\sum_{k=1}^m c_k x^k(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}  x^{n}  a_{n}-\sum_{n=0}^{m-k-1}  x^{n}  a_{n})\\
&=A_{m-1}(x)+\sum_{k=1}^m c_k x^k(A(x)-A_{m-k-1}(x))\\
&=A_{m-1}(x)+A(x)\sum_{k=1}^m c_k x^k-\sum_{k=1}^m c_k x^kA_{m-k-1}(x)\\
\end{array}
$

so
$\begin{array}\\
A(x)(1-\sum_{k=1}^m c_k x^k)
&=A_{m-1}(x)-\sum_{k=1}^m c_k x^kA_{m-k-1}(x)\\
&=A_{m-1}(x)-\sum_{k=0}^{m-1} c_{m-k} x^{m-k}A_{k-1}(x)
\qquad k \to m-k\\
&=A_{m-1}(x)-\sum_{k=0}^{m-1} c_{m-k} x^{m-k}\sum_{n=0}^{k-1} a_n x^n\\
&=A_{m-1}(x)-\sum_{n=0}^{m-2}\sum_{k=n+1}^{m-1} c_{m-k} x^{m-k} a_n x^n\\
&=A_{m-1}(x)-\sum_{n=0}^{m-2}\sum_{k=n+1}^{m-1} c_{m-k} a_n x^{n+m-k}\\
&=A_{m-1}(x)-\sum_{n=0}^{m-2}\sum_{r=n+m-m+1}^{n+m-n-1} c_{m-n-m+r} a_n x^{r}
\qquad r = n+m-k, k = n+m-r\\
&=A_{m-1}(x)-\sum_{n=0}^{m-2}\sum_{r=n+1}^{m-1} c_{r-n} a_n x^{r}\\
&=A_{m-1}(x)-\sum_{r=1}^{m-1}\sum_{n=0}^{r-1} c_{r-n} a_n x^{r}\\
&=\sum_{r=0}^{m-1} a_r x^r-\sum_{r=1}^{m-1}x^r\sum_{n=0}^{r-1} c_{r-n} a_n\\
&=a_0+\sum_{r=1}^{m-1}  x^r(a_r-\sum_{n=0}^{r-1} c_{r-n} a_n)\\
&=\sum_{r=0}^{m-1}  x^r(a_r-\sum_{n=0}^{r-1} c_{r-n} a_n)\\
&=\sum_{r=0}^{m-1}  x^r(a_r-\sum_{n=1}^{r} c_{n} a_{r-n})\\
&=\sum_{r=0}^{m-1}  x^r(a_r-\sum_{k=1}^{r} c_{k} a_{r-k})\\
&=\sum_{r=0}^{m-1}  x^rb_r
\qquad b_r=a_r-\sum_{k=1}^{r} c_{k} a_{r-k}\\
\end{array}
$

Therefore

$A(x)
=\dfrac{\sum_{r=0}^{m-1}  x^rb_r}{1-\sum_{k=1}^m c_k x^k}
=\dfrac{\sum_{r=0}^{m-1}  x^r(a_r-\sum_{k=1}^{r} c_{k} a_{r-k})}{1-\sum_{k=1}^m c_k x^k}
$.

Explicit values of the
first few
$b_r$.

$b_0
=a_0\\
b_1
= a_1-c_1a_0\\
b_2
= a_2-c_1a_1-c_2a_0\\
b_3
= a_3-c_1a_2-c_2a_1-c_3a_0\\
$

For $m=1$,
when
$a_n
=c_1a_{n-1}
$
for $n \ge 1
$,
and the initial term is
$a_0$,
$$A(x)
=\dfrac{a_0
}{1-c_1x}
$$

For $m=2$,
when
$a_n
=c_1a_{n-1}+c_2a_{n-2}
$
for $n \ge 2
$,
and the initial terms are
$a_0$ and $a_1$,
$$A(x)
=\dfrac{a_0
+x(a_1-c_1a_{0})}{1-c_1x-c_2x^2}
=\dfrac{a_0
+b_1x}{1-c_1x-c_2x^2}
$$

---

Suppose
$C(x)
=1-\sum_{k=1}^m c_k x^k
=\prod_{k=1}^m (1-d_kx)
$
where all the $d_k$
are distinct
and non-zero.
We want to find
the partial function expansion
$e_{1..m}$ so that
$\dfrac1{C(x)}
=\dfrac1{1-\sum_{k=1}^m c_k x^k}
=\sum_{j=1}^m \dfrac{e_j}{1-d_jx}
$.

$\begin{array}\\
\dfrac1{C(x)}
&=\sum_{j=1}^m \dfrac{e_j}{1-d_jx}\\
\text{so}\\
1
&=\sum_{j=1}^m \dfrac{e_jC(x)}{1-d_jx}\\
&=\sum_{j=1}^m \dfrac{e_j\prod_{k=1}^m (1-d_kx)}{1-d_jx}\\
&=\sum_{j=1}^m e_j\prod_{k=1, k\ne j}^m (1-d_kx)\\
\end{array}
$

Letting $x = \dfrac1{d_j}$,
$1
=e_j\prod_{k=1, k\ne j}^m (1-\frac{d_k}{d_j})
=e_j\prod_{k=1, k\ne j}^m (\frac{d_j-d_k}{d_j})
$
so
$e_j
=\prod_{k=1, k\ne j}^m (\frac{d_j}{d_j-d_k})
$.

So

$\begin{array}\\
A(x)
&=\dfrac{\sum_{r=0}^{m-1}  x^rb_r}{1-\sum_{k=1}^m c_k x^k}\\
&=\sum_{r=0}^{m-1}  x^rb_r\sum_{j=1}^m \dfrac{e_j}{1-d_jx}\\
&=\sum_{r=0}^{m-1}  x^rb_r\sum_{j=1}^m e_j\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}(d_jx)^i\\
&=\sum_{j=1}^me_j\sum_{r=0}^{m-1}  x^rb_r\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}d_j^ix^i\\
&=\sum_{j=1}^me_j\sum_{r=0}^{m-1}  b_r\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}d_j^ix^{i+r}\\
&=\sum_{j=1}^me_j\sum_{r=0}^{m-1}  b_r\sum_{i=r}^{\infty}d_j^{i-r}x^{i}\\
&=\sum_{j=1}^me_j\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}x^{i}\sum_{r=0}^{\min(m-1, i)}  b_rd_j^{i-r}\\
&=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}x^{i}\sum_{j=1}^me_j\sum_{r=0}^{\min(m-1, i)}  b_rd_j^{i-r}\\
&=\sum_{i=0}^{m-1}x^{i}\sum_{j=1}^me_j\sum_{r=0}^{\min(m-1, i)}  b_rd_j^{i-r}+\sum_{i=m}^{\infty}x^{i}\sum_{j=1}^me_j\sum_{r=0}^{\min(m-1, i)}  b_rd_j^{i-r}\\
&=\sum_{i=0}^{m-1}x^{i}\sum_{j=1}^me_j\sum_{r=0}^{i}  b_rd_j^{i-r}+\sum_{i=m}^{\infty}x^{i}\sum_{j=1}^me_j\sum_{r=0}^{m-1}  b_rd_j^{i-r}\\
\end{array}
$

For $n \ge m$,

$\begin{array}\\
a_n=
&\sum_{j=1}^me_j\sum_{r=0}^{m-1}  b_rd_j^{n-r}\\
&\sum_{j=1}^me_jd_j^n\sum_{r=0}^{m-1}  b_rd_j^{-r}\\
&\sum_{j=1}^me_jf_jd_j^n
\qquad f_j=\sum_{r=0}^{m-1}  b_rd_j^{-r}\\
\end{array}
$

Therefore if
$$
a_n
=\sum_{k=1}^m c_k a_{n-k}
\text{ for } n \ge m\\
$$
where

$$
1-\sum_{k=1}^m c_k x^k
=\prod_{k=1}^m (1-d_kx)
\text{ with all the } d_k
\text{ distinct}
$$
then
$$a_n=
\sum_{j=1}^me_jf_jd_j^n
\text{ for } n \ge m\\
$$

where

$$b_r=a_r-\sum_{k=1}^{r} c_{k} a_{r-k}
\text{ for }0 \le r \le m-1
$$
$$e_j
=\prod_{k=1, k\ne j}^m (\frac{d_j}{d_j-d_k})
$$
$$f_j
=\sum_{r=0}^{m-1}  b_rd_j^{-r}
$$

Note that
for $n \ge m$,

$a_n
=\sum_{j=1}^me_jf_jd_j^n
$

so that,
if
$h$ is the index of
the largest $d_j$,
then

$a_n
\approx e_hf_hd_h^n
$

which is the
well-known exponential growth.

Answer (score 0):

Hint.

From

$$
a_n x^n-a a_{n-1}x^n-b a_{n-2}x^n=0
$$

we have

$$
T(x) = \frac{\phi(x)}{1-ax-bx^2} = \frac{\phi(x)}{b}\left(\frac{A}{x-x_1}+\frac{B}{x-x_2}\right)
$$

where $x_1,x_2$ are the roots from $1-ax-bx^2=0$ and $\phi(x)$ is the initial conditions polynomial. Here $T(x) = \sum a_k x^k$

Comment: What is an initial conditions polynomial?

Comment: A polynomial involving coefficients $a_0,a_1$

Comment: Would $a_1 T^3+a_0 T^2-a a_0 T$ be my initial conditions polynomial?

Comment: Are you saying to instead just partial fractions decomposee the denominator?